# How do i know, when view is drawn?

Tags: android, view

My `Activity` layout has `View`, i have get Y position this view at the beginning of the program, but if i shall insert in bottom method `onCreate` , i get position `value = 0`. How i can know, when view is drawn and get her Y position. I try get Y position when i click on button, position get good, but i have get position without using the button.

I get position:

```
private float cardsStartPosition = 0;
if (cardsStartPosition == 0) {
    cardsStartPosition = commonCardContainer.getY();
}
```

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method..It works fine for me.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = YourView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        //do your stuff here                    

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a global layout listener to your view, you will get notified when layout is done and your view has dimensions ...

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            //Here you can get your dimensions
            int width = view.getWidth();
            //View.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention just View. So if that means it's your custom view, you can override the `onLayout()`:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  ...;
}
```

This way you can observe any layout changes of your view. If you're also interested in size changes, there's also the `onSizeChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  ...;
}
```

If it's not your custom view, I'd go with the Ketan Ahir's way.